# Delete songs from Spotify playlist

Tags: spotify

In the new Spotify Web API you are able to create a playlist for a user and add songs to it. Is it possible to delete songs from a playlist (give you have the correct permission scope)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This function is not added yet.

Comment: Any hints if it will be added in the future? This is very useful for custom made discovery services. Without the ability to edit playlists, the user will instead have to deal with new playlists over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove items from a playlist by using `DELETE` method on this endpoint:
`https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/{playlist_id}/tracks`

where the request body should contain: `tracks` - a required array of objects containing Spotify URI strings.

example:

```
{ "tracks": [{ "uri": "spotify:track:4iV5W9uYEdYUVa79Axb7Rh" },{ "uri": "spotify:track:1301WleyT98MSxVHPZCA6M" }, { "uri": "spotify:episode:512ojhOuo1ktJprKbVcKyQ" }] }
```

Test the endpoint here:
https://developer.spotify.com/console/delete-playlist-tracks/

Link to the documentation: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/remove-tracks-playlist/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)